# Moving Excerpt from Admin Sidebar below Post Title

Tags: wordpress, admin, wordpress-gutenberg, create-guten-block

I would like to remove edit excerpt section from the admin's right sidebar and move to the main editing block below the post title and above the Gutenberg blocks. Is there any option to add code to functions.php?
I only found old code for pre Gutenberg solutions.